# MPI_Comm_spawn and MPI_Reduce

Tags: c++, mpi

I have two programs. The "master" which spawns "workers" which perform some calculations and I want the master to get the results from the workers and store the sum. I am trying to use MPI_Reduce to collect the results from the workers, and the workers use MPI_Reduce to send to the masters MPI_Comm. I am not sure if that is correct. Here are my programs:

Master:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { 
    int world_size, universe_size, *universe_sizep, flag; 

    int rc, send, recv;

    // intercommunicator
    MPI_Comm everyone;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv); 
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size); 

    if (world_size != 1) {
        cout << "Top heavy with management" << endl;
    } 

    MPI_Attr_get(MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_UNIVERSE_SIZE, &universe_sizep, &flag);  
    if (!flag) { 
        cout << "This MPI does not support UNIVERSE_SIZE. How many processes total?";
        cout << "Enter the universe size: ";
        cin >> universe_size; 
    } else {
        universe_size = *universe_sizep;
    }
    if (universe_size == 1) {
        cout << "No room to start workers" << endl;
    }

    MPI_Comm_spawn("so_worker", MPI_ARGV_NULL, universe_size-1,  
             MPI_INFO_NULL, 0, MPI_COMM_SELF, &everyone,  
             MPI_ERRCODES_IGNORE);

    send = 0;

    rc = MPI_Reduce(&send, &recv, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, 0, everyone);

    // store result of recv ...
    // other calculations here
    cout << "From spawned workers recv: " << recv << endl;

    MPI_Finalize(); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Worker:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { 

    int rc, send,recv;


    int parent_size, parent_id, my_id, numprocs; 
    // parent intercomm
    MPI_Comm parent; 
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv); 

    MPI_Comm_get_parent(&parent); 
    if (parent == MPI_COMM_NULL) {
        cout << "No parent!" << endl;
    }
    MPI_Comm_remote_size(parent, &parent_size); 
    MPI_Comm_rank(parent, &parent_id) ; 
    //cout << "Parent is of size: " << size << endl;
    if (parent_size != 1) {
        cout << "Something's wrong with the parent" << endl;
    }

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_id) ;     
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs) ;  

    cout << "I'm child process rank "<< my_id << " and we are " << numprocs << endl;
    cout << "The parent process rank "<< parent_id << " and we are " << parent_size << endl;

    // get value of send
    send = 7; // just an example
    recv = 0;

    rc = MPI_Reduce(&send, &recv, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, parent_id, parent);
    if (rc != MPI_SUCCESS)
        cout << my_id << " failure on mpi_reduce in WORKER" << endl;

    MPI_Finalize(); 
    return 0; 
}
```

I compiled both and execute like this (mpic++ for osx):

```
mpic++ so_worker.cpp -o so_worker
mpic++ so_master.cpp -o so_master
mpirun -n 1 so_master
```

Is this the correct way to run a master that spawns the workers?

In the master I always get 0 back from the MPI_Reduce. Can I use MPI_reduce from intercommunicators or should I use MPI_Send from workers and MPI_Recv from master? I'm really not sure why it's not working.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`MPI_Comm_get_parent` returns the parent intercommunicator that encompasses the original process and all the spawned ones. In this case calling `MPI_Comm_rank(parent, &parent_id)` does not return the rank of the parent but rather the rank of the current process in the local group of the intercommunicator:

```
I'm child process rank 0 and we are 3
The parent process **rank 0** and we are 1
I'm child process rank 1 and we are 3
The parent process **rank 1** and we are 1
I'm child process rank 2 and we are 3
The parent process **rank 2** and we are 1
```

(observe how the highlighted values differ - one would expect that the rank of the parent process should be the same, shouldn't it?)

That's why the `MPI_Reduce()` call would not succeed as all worker processes specify different values for the root rank. Since originally there was one master process, its rank in remote group of `parent` would be `0` and hence all workers should specify `0` as the root to `MPI_Reduce`:

```
//
// Worker code
//
rc = MPI_Reduce(&send, &recv, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, 0, parent);
```

This is only half of the problem. The other half is that rooted collective operations (e.g. `MPI_REDUCE`) operate a bit different with intercommunicators. One first has to decide which of the two groups would host the root. Once the root group is identified, the root process has to pass `MPI_ROOT` as the value of `root` in `MPI_REDUCE` and all other processes in the root group must pass `MPI_PROC_NULL`. That is the processes in the receiving group do not take part in the rooted collective operation at all. Since the master code is written so that there could be only one process in the master's group, then it would suffice to change the call to `MPI_Reduce` in the master code to:

```
//
// Master code
//
rc = MPI_Reduce(&send, &recv, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, MPI_ROOT, everyone);
```

Note that the master also does not participate in the reduction operation itself, e.g. the value of `sendbuf` (`&send` in this case) is irrelevant as the root would not be sending data to be reduced - it merely collects the result of the reduction performed over the values from the processes in the remote group.

Comment: @Hristo Iliev
Here you've hardcoded the rank of the root to be 0 in the worker code.
I wonder if there is a way to find out the rank of the root from within the worker.

Comment: @takwing, in this particular case the initial MPI job consists of a single MPI process, hence from the point of view of the worker processes, the remote group of the parent intercommunicator has a single rank in it and it is always 0.

Comment: @Hristo, I guess the way I asked my question wasn't clear. Actually, my question is not limited to this particular code. I am looking for a way to find the rank of a process from within the other group? 
Let's take this scenario:
What if the root may change at run time from process to process, meaning that workers now have to figure out what the rank of the root on the other side of the inter-communicator is, with respect to the remote group. Is there a way to extract such information from the worker side?

Comment: @takwing, have the actual root from the remote broadcast its rank. I don't have any better idea. One usually fixes such processes algorithmically or uses some precoded logic (possibly with communication) to determine it. I see no reason for the spawned job to not be able to use the same logic to find out which the root process is.