# mpi_comm_spawn error: MPI Application rank 0 killed before MPI_Finalize() with signal 11

Tags: c, mpi

I'm trying to run an mpi program using MPI_Comm_Spawn. I spawn 1 worker program, and then call MPI_reduce in both programs, to add up some results. For some reason, the application hangs at MPI_Comm_spawn, then aborts after a minute. The spawned process only gets to its code segment where its calls MPI_reduce after this happens. The application then continues to hang, and then gives some more errors in the command prompt. What *should* happen is that both the spawned and master programs reach the MPI_Reduce call, and the master program gets a sum, and outputs that sum.

Here's the output, I've put a <> where its MPI's output, and not my own

```
world size = 1   
About to call MPI_Comm_spawn with 2 workers...   
parent result is 3.141668952    
numDarts for child: 500000000  
argv[1] = 500000000  
<>MPI Application rank 0 killed before MPI_Finalize() with signal 11  
spawned process got result: 3.141668952  
Spawned process about to send message back to parent  
<>piworker: Rank 1:0: MPI_Finalize: IBV connection to 0 on card 0 is broken
<>piworker: Rank 1:0: MPI_Finalize: ibv_poll_cq(): bad status 12  
<>piworker: Rank 1:0: MPI_Finalize: self n93 peer n93 (rank: 0)  
<>piworker: Rank 1:0: MPI_Finalize: error message: transport retry exceeded error
```

Here's the master program's code:

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "globals.h"


int randSign();
double randFloat();
double dboard();


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int world_size, flag;
    MPI_Comm everyone;           /* intercommunicator */
    char worker_program[100];
    int universe_size;

    //  MPI_Comm_get_attr(MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_UNIVERSE_SIZE, &universe_size, &flag);
    //   printf("universe size: %i\n", universe_size);

    int numDarts = 1000000000;
    int numWorkers = 2;

    char* args[1];
    if(argc >= 2)
    {
      numWorkers = atoi(argv[1]);
    }
      if(argc >= 3)
    numDarts = atoi(argv[2]);

   MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
   MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

   printf("world size = %i\n", world_size);
   if (world_size != 1)
        printf("Top heavy with management\n");

   int numDartsWorker = numDarts/numWorkers;
   int numDartsMaster = numDarts/numWorkers + (numDarts % numWorkers); //the master computes the leftover
   args[0] = malloc(256 * sizeof(char));
   sprintf(args[0], "%i", numDartsWorker);
   printf("argument passing to workers: %s\n", args[0]);
   /*
    * Now spawn the workers. Note that there is a run-time determination
    * of what type of worker to spawn, and presumably this calculation must
    * be done at run time and cannot be calculated before starting
    * the program. If everything is known when the application is
    * first started, it is generally better to start them all at once
    * in a single MPI_COMM_WORLD.
    */
   printf("About to call MPI_Comm_spawn with %i workers...\n", numWorkers);
   int resultLen = 0;

   double myresult = dboard(numDartsMaster);
   printf("parent result is %.9f\n", myresult);


   //the master counts as a worker, hence the -1
   MPI_Comm_spawn("piworker", args, numWorkers-1, MPI_INFO_NULL, 0, MPI_COMM_SELF,
                   &everyone, MPI_ERRCODES_IGNORE);

   double pisum = 24;
   int rc = MPI_Reduce(&myresult, &pisum, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, 0, everyone);

   if (rc != MPI_SUCCESS)
        printf("failure on mpi_reduce\n");

   free(args);
   /*
    * Parallel code here. The communicator "everyone" can be used
    * to communicate with the spawned processes, which have ranks 0,..
    * MPI_UNIVERSE_SIZE-1 in the remote group of the intercommunicator
    * "everyone".
    */

   //receive the results
   int i=1;
   MPI_Status status;
   double avgpi = pisum/(double)numWorkers;
   printf("With %i workers, %i darts, estimated value of pi is: %.9f\n", numWorkers, numDarts, avgpi);

   MPI_Finalize();
   return 0;
}
```

The code for the worker (spawned) program

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int size;
   MPI_Comm parent;
   MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
   MPI_Comm_get_parent(&parent);
   if (parent == MPI_COMM_NULL)
        printf("No parent!");
   int taskid;
   MPI_Comm_remote_size(parent, &size);
   MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&taskid);
   double pisum = 0;
   int resultLen = 0;
   char parentName[256];
   int numDarts;


   if (size != 1)
   {
        printf("Something's wrong with the parent");
        return 1;
   }
   /*
    * Parallel code here.
    * The manager is represented as the process with rank 0 in (the remote
    * group of) the parent communicator.  If the workers need to communicate
    * among themselves, they can use MPI_COMM_WORLD.
    */
   if(argc >= 2)
        numDarts = atoi(argv[1]);
   else
   {
      printf("Error for: %i, number of darts not specified.\n", taskid);
   }
   printf("numDarts for child: %i\n", numDarts);
   printf("argv[1] = %s\n", argv[1]);
   double myPiSum = dboard(numDarts);
   printf("spawned process got result: %.9f\n", myPiSum);
   printf("Spawned process about to send message back to parent\n");
 //MPI_Send((void *)&myPiSum, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 1, parent);

   int rc = MPI_Reduce(&myPiSum, &pisum, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, 0, parent);
   if(rc != MPI_SUCCESS)
        printf("%d: Problem with mpi_reduce\n");


   printf("Sent message back to parent");
   MPI_Finalize();
   return 0;
}
```

Hopefully, the cause of this will be more apparent to someone with more experience with this. I've been trying all sorts of things, which is why I have so many printf calls.

Comment: The `MPI_Comm_spawn` call is missing from the master's code.

Comment: Fixed (the post, not the problem). Sorry about that, I'm coding this from an ssh terminal, and copy/pasting can be difficult in that environment.

Comment: The root argument to `MPI_Reduce` in the master's code should be `MPI_ROOT` and not `0`. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14734028/1374437) to a question much similar to yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the master process dies because of incorrect usage of `free()`:

```c
char* args[1];
...
args[0] = malloc(256 * sizeof(char));
...
free(args);
```

You are trying to free non-heap (stack) memory and `free(args)` triggers an abort in modern `glibc` versions. The correct invocation should be:

```c
free(args[0]);
```

Other than that, `MPI_Reduce` does not work the way you expect it work when called with an intercommunicator. You must change the master code so that it passes `MPI_ROOT` as the root argument to `MPI_Reduce` and then you have to manually add the master's value since it would not be used during the reduction (only values from processes in the remote group are being reduced - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14734028/1374437)).